# Maximum Modulus Exercise

Tags: complex-analysis, optimization, maximum-principle

Using the maximum modulus theorem in complex analysis, what is a good technique for finding the maximum of $|f(z)|$ on $|z|\le 1$, when $f(z)=z^2-3z+2$?

Got some really nice answers below, so I thought I'd share an image showing some contours of $|z^2-3z+2|$. Note that the magnitude does increase as we move "as far as possible" from the zeros  (phrase used in answer below). And, at $z=-1$, note how the contour $|z^2-3z+2|=6$ is tangent to the circle $|z|=1$.

[image]

Comment: Looks like I found one technique: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163543/maximum-value-of-the-modulus-of-a-holomorphic-function Are there any other suggestions?

Comment: What's wrong with simply setting $z = e^{i\theta}$ and setting the derivative w.r.t. $\theta$ equal to 0?

Answer (score 13):

By the maximum modulus principle, the maximum is on the unit circle $|z| = 1$. Since $f$ has zeroes at $1$ and $2$, we would expect the maximum to be "as far as possible" away from those, i.e. at $x = -1$. Indeed, we have $f(-1) = 6$, and by the triangle inequality
$$|f(z)| = |z^2-3z+2| \leq |z|^2+3|z|+2 = 6$$
on the unit circle. So $x=-1$ gives a maximum, but we still have to show that there are no other maxima.

Identifying $\mathbb C$ with $\mathbb R^2$, writing $z = x+yi$, the function becomes
$$f(x,y) = (x^2-y^2-3x+2) +  (2xy-3y)i$$
and we want to maximize
$$|f(x,y)|^2 = (x^2-y^2-3x+2)^2 + (2xy-3y)^2$$
subject to the condition $x^2+y^2 = 1$. We can express $|f(x,y)|^2$ in terms of $x$ only, using $y^2=1-x^2$:
\begin{align*}|f(x,y)|^2 &= (2x^2-3x+1)^2 + (2x-3)^2(1-x^2)\\
&= 8x^2-18x+10.
\end{align*}
The only maximum of this in $[-1,1]$ is at $x = -1$ .

Comment: Really nice explanation. Little typo here: $$|f(x,y)|^2 = (x^2-y^2-3x+3)^2 + (2xy-3y)^2$$

Comment: marlu, is that true in general that the point on the boundary at which $\vert f \vert$ is maximal is farthest away from the zeros?

Comment: I don't know. One might be able to prove something like that in general, but first one would have to say what exactly is meant by "farthest away from the zeroes".

Comment: @marlu sir, isn't by traingle inequality and by maximum modulus theorem it follows that maximum value of function $f(z)$ cannot exceed than $6$? and clearly it occurs when $z=-1$ Why need of rest of the calculation? Please sir help me...

Comment: Yes, if you just want to know the maximum value (6) you don't need the rest of the calculation. You need it if you want to know where this value occurs (at $z=-1$ and no other point).