# Finding maximum value of $|f(z)|$ using Maximum modulus theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, maximum-principle

In the question asked here→ [Maximum Modulus Exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/325767/168676)

**I want to know, if we just want to find maximum value of $|f(z)|$, why 'Marlu' Sir in his answer (here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/325832/168676) has done calculations to show that there are no other Maxima?**

**My attempt**: as $f(z)=z^2-3z+2$ is analytic inside and on $|z|=1$ hence by maximum modulus theorem, maximum value of $|f(z)|$ occurs on boundary! 
and by traingle inequality,

$|f(z)|=|z^2-3z+2|≤|z^2|+3|z|+2$

$$≤6$$ (since on the boundary, $|z|=1$)

**So from here**, we know, maximum value of $|f(z)|$ **cannot exceed** $6$ and the fact that,  at point  $z=-1$ which is on boundary, $f(-1)=6$ **confirms** that, maximum value of $|f(z)|$ is $6$ is am I correct? Please help me...

Comment: Some times, "find the maximum" also means to find the points where the maximum occurs.

Comment: @Arthur sir, if we just need to find maximum value of $|f(z)|$ then is there is need of those extra calculations? Please help me..

Comment: If you only need the maximum value, and not the point(s) where it occurs, then your argument is enough: the absolute value can't be larger than $6$, and it does equal $6$ somewhere, so $6$ is the maximum.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, for your reply, you made my day.....:-)

Answer (score -1):

No, 6 is just an upper bound but not the maximum modulus, check out the zill-complex analysis book.

Check out my [annotated image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbVqv.png) if you still have issue.